# Find items in inner array - angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a function in `angularJS` that uses `find` to check if an item exists in an array;

```
function matchCartItem(item) {
    return $scope.cart[0].cart_items.find(function(itm) {
        return itm.item_id === item.item_id
    });
}
```

As you can see I pass an `item` to the function then i check if the `item_id` of the passed `item` can be found in the `items` in the `cart_items` array

This works great but now I want to modify it.

`cart_items` has an inner array `cart_modifier_items`
. When a `cart_item` is passed it contains `cart_modifier_items`. My function at the moment only checks for matching `cart_item`

How can I change this function to also check the `cart_modifier_items`?

So I want to check for matching `item.item_id` in `$scope.cart[0].cart_items` -- my function does this

But also check for matching `item.cart_modifier_item[i] in`$scope.cart[0].cart_items[i].cart_modifier_items`where`i`is like looping through all the`cart_items`

Any help/guidance appreciated

Data structure of **item**

```
cart_item: [
    {
      "id": 159,
      "item_id": 20,
      "name": "Empanadas (Choice of 2)",
      "description": "Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella",
      "price": 700,
      "available": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
      "updated_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
      "menu_category_id": 41,
      "restaurant_id": 11,
      "cart_modifier_items": [
          {
              "id": 34,
              "item_id": 29,
              "name": "Diced Beef",
              "price": 0,
              "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
              "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
              "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
              "restaurant_id": 11,
              "menu_item_id": 159
          },
          {
              "id": 35,
              "item_id": 10,
              "name": "Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella",
              "price": 0,
              "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
              "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
              "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
              "restaurant_id": 11,
              "menu_item_id": 159
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show data structure and expected results. Note that `find()` does not have universal browser support and requires using a polyfill

Comment: @charlietfl I've added the structure of the `item`. How can I do this without using `find`

Answer (score 1):

Use standard `some` instead of find:

```
function matchCartItem(item) {
    return $scope.cart[0].cart_items.some(function(itm) {
        return itm.item_id === item.item_id;
    });
}
```

`some` checks if any item in array satisfies condition.

Comment: What about the inner array? `cart_modifier_items`

Comment: I want to be able to loop through the inner array of `cart_items` and return a single `true`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just need to loop twice to find the good cart modifier item :

```
var findModifier = function(itemId, cartModifierId, cart_items){
  var itemLen = cart_items.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < itemLen; ++i){
    if(cart_items[i].id === itemId){
      var modifierLen = cart_items[i].cart_modifier_items.length;
      for(var j = 0; j < modifierLen; ++j){
        if(cart_items[i].cart_modifier_items[j].id == cartModifierId){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

See in plunker :
https://plnkr.co/edit/oYWL8OKbzmHUvUG0sCmi?p=preview

Comment: I can see you're passing many items to the function... all I can pass is the `item`

Comment: I only pass :
your $scope.cart[0].cart_items as cart_items
your "item" as itemId
and the id of the cart_modifier to find.

Do you want to pass only the cart_modifier_id ?

Comment: `item = cart_item` and the `cart_modifier_items` are inside the `cart_item`..... so `item` contains everything. I want to check for `item` inside `$scope.cart[0].cart_items`

Comment: Ok, but you want to : 
 find the cart item with  id = itm, and once it is done, find the cart modifier with another given id ?

Comment: Yes correct, first check if `cart_item` exists in `$scope.cart[0].cart_items`.. If it exists then check that every `cart_modifier_items` of the `cart_item` we found also exists